# Accordion not collapsing

Tags: accordion

The sections on our 'meeting minutes' page aren't collapsing and I don't know what to do to fix this.  I don't know HTML, or enough to be dangerous.  Below is the HTML for the page - if somebody could point out where this is wrong or what needs to be changed / added I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Stan

[tm_pb_section admin_label="section" transparent_background="on" allow_player_pause="off" inner_shadow="off" parallax="off" parallax_method="off" custom_padding="20px|20px|20px|20px" padding_mobile="on" make_fullwidth="off" use_custom_width="off" width_unit="on" make_equal="off" use_custom_gutter="off"][tm_pb_row admin_label="row" make_fullwidth="on" use_custom_width="off" use_grid_padding="on" width_unit="on" custom_padding="20px|20px|20px|20px" padding_mobile="off" allow_player_pause="off" parallax="off" parallax_method="off" make_equal="off" parallax_1="off" parallax_method_1="off" column_padding_mobile="on"][tm_pb_column type="4_4"][tm_pb_text admin_label="Text" text_orientation="left" use_border_color="off" border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid"]

## Board Meeting Minutes

[/tm_pb_text][/tm_pb_column][/tm_pb_row][tm_pb_row admin_label="Row" make_fullwidth="on" use_custom_width="off" use_grid_padding="on" width_unit="on" custom_padding="20px|20px|20px|20px" padding_mobile="off" allow_player_pause="off" parallax="off" parallax_method="off" make_equal="off" parallax_1="off" parallax_method_1="off" column_padding_mobile="on"][tm_pb_column type="4_4"][tm_pb_accordion admin_label="Accordion" use_border_color="off" border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" custom_padding="||20px|"]

[tm_pb_accordion_item title="2021"]

Annual Meeting Minutes

[January](https://sugarwood.org/wp-content/uploads/JanMinutes2021.pdf)

[February](https://sugarwood.org/wp-content/uploads/FebMinutes2021.pdf)

[/tm_pb_accordion_item]

[/tm_pb_accordion][tm_pb_accordion admin_label="Accordion" use_border_color="off" border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid" custom_padding="||20px|"]

[/tm_pb_accordion_item]

[/tm_pb_accordion][/tm_pb_column][/tm_pb_row][/tm_pb_section]